# Is it possible to use xs:group in xs:choice so that only one from the group is selected?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I want to define complex types like AorBorC and ABCOrMore below, which should have only one element from a predefined group (group1 below). Here, I want that AOrBorC can have only 1 occurrence of element from group1 while ABCOrMore can have multiple occurrences of  element chosen from group1. I could populate the choices individually in the choice element, but this has to done in multiple places and I wanted to know if a group could be used instead.

I tried the following. But it's allowing one or multiple occurrences of the group as a whole instead or its elements.

Any help would be appreciated!

```
<xs:group name="group1" >
    <xs:sequence>   
        <xs:element name="a" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
        <xs:element name="b" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
        <xs:element name="c" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
    </xs:sequence>   
</xs:group>

<xs:complexType name="AorBorC">
    <xs:choice minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
        <xs:group ref="group1" />
    </xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>       


<xs:complexType name="ABCOrMore"> 
    <xs:choice minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"> 
        <xs:group ref="group1" /> 
    </xs:choice> 
</xs:complexType>
```

---

```
XML to be supported:
<ns0:Root xmlns:ns0="http://Scratch.ABC">
  <AorBorC>
    <c>c_1</c>
  </AorBorC>
  <ABCOrMore>
    <a>a_1</a>
    <a>a_2</a>
    <a>a_3</a>
  </ABCOrMore>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have your choice in the wrong place

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="http://Scratch.ABC" targetNamespace="http://Scratch.ABC" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="Root">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="AorBorC" type="group1" />
        <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="ABCOrMore" type="group1" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:complexType name="group1">
    <xs:choice>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="a" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="b" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="c" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:choice>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

XML

```
<ns0:Root xmlns:ns0="http://Scratch.ABC">
  <AorBorC>
    <a>a_1</a>
  </AorBorC>
  <ABCOrMore>
    <a>a_2</a>
  </ABCOrMore>
  <ABCOrMore>
    <b>b_1</b>
  </ABCOrMore>
</ns0:Root>
```

Or if you want

```
<ns0:Root xmlns:ns0="http://Scratch.ABC">
  <AorBorC>
    <a>a_2</a>
  </AorBorC>
  <ABCOrMore>
    <a>a_2</a>
    <c>c_1</c>
    <b>b_1</b>
  </ABCOrMore>
</ns0:Root>
```

Then

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="http://Scratch.ABC" xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" targetNamespace="http://Scratch.ABC" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="Root">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="AorBorC" type="AorBorCType" />
        <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="ABCOrMore" type="AorBorCMoreType" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:complexType name="AorBorCType">
    <xs:choice minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="a" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="b" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="c" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:choice>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="AorBorCMoreType">
    <xs:choice minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="a" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="b" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="c" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:choice>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

EDIT

With your question clarified, this schema should fit the bill

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="http://Scratch.ABC" xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" targetNamespace="http://Scratch.ABC" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="Root">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="AorBorC" type="AorBorCType" />
        <xs:element name="AorBorCMore" type="AorBorCMoreType" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:complexType name="AorBorCType">
    <xs:choice>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="a" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="b" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="c" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:choice>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="AorBorCMoreType">
    <xs:choice>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="a" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="b" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="c" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:choice>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick help! I want to understand if there is any way to achieve the second XML you posted (but with only one type of ABCOrMore should be allowed - adding XML in my original post), without repeating a,b,c elements in two different xs:choice's?

Comment: The solution you posted works but it does not maintain one list for a,b,c elements. Is it possible to do the same thing and not repeat a,b,c elements in 2 lists?

Comment: That's is exactly what list 2 (AorBorCMoreType) does. The maxOccurs is below the choice, so you should only be able to have a or b or c exclusively.  I tested it and a file with more than one failed to validate.

Comment: sure but I dont want to define AOrBOrCType and AOrBOrCOrMoreType in separate lists! I want them to refer the same list.

Comment: That is just not possible as they have different maximum occurrences.